# Download Android SDK programmatically

Tags: java, android, sdk

Is there a way to download android sdk from android website programmatically? Does google provide any rest api/url for that? I have developed one developer side application for which I determine if android sdk is installed or not, if not installed I should be able to download latest sdk from Android website programmatically. Is this possible?

Comment: You could analyze what the SDK Manager does. It is fetching some [XML files](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml) to determine what packages are available. That API is probably not meant to be used by everyone but it's there.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try. Where can i find code for sdk manager?

Comment: Not sure if it is open source or otherwise available. Try a network sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to check what files it fetches & maybe use a [decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to look into it's code (`./android-sdk/tools/lib/sdkmanager.jar`).

Answer (score 1):

Decompilation as suggested in one of the comments is overkill. You just need to parse the XML content from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml . Check the SDK:url tag and use that to fetch (wget, curl, httpclient, ...) the required zip files.